# Sql Query giving error missing operator while using row_number in it

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oledb

I'm trying to find unique rows based on three different columns

Here is the query I've written but I get an error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'row_number() OVER ( partition BY F1, F2,F3 order by F1)

Here is the query

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3 
FROM
   (SELECT  
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F1, F2, F3 ORDER BY F1) AS rn 
    FROM 
        tblName) a 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Can someone please figure out what's wrong with this query?

I'm using this query in a C# program to extract data from an Excel sheet using oledb. Thanks in advance.

Here is my C# code

```
OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
data.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: If you take your query, and run it directly on your SQL Server database, do you also get the error?  If not, then please post your C# code.

Comment: If you're just trying to find unique values, couldn't you use "select distinct F1, F2, F3"?

Comment: I'm not getting error in Sql Server Database

Comment: using ditinct over F1, F2, F3 might not get the exact results so I need to use row_number

Comment: Are you sure you are querying sql server? Show the full code with connection string... `extract data from excel sheet using oledb.`

Comment: I'm query excel sheet using Oledb. But I've tried the same query in sql server and it's working fine but in case of excel sheet it doesn't.

Comment: This query will work just fine in **SQL Server**, but I don't think you can apply it to an **Excel sheet** using OleDB :....

Comment: You can not do row_number in excel. Google it...

Comment: is there any other option I can use instead of row_number for excel sheets ?

Comment: Import data from excel sheet to sql server and use your query in sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to try to get the row number, if you're asking SQL Sevrer to fetch rows with your 3 distinct values.

Supposing two rows *do* have the same 3 values in them... what row number should it return ?

What you should do is use `RANK()` (rather than row number) with `PARTITION`, and filter it with a "`WHERE RANK = 1`" filter.

There's a good example here:
[RANK](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/Rank.htm)

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3 
FROM
   (SELECT F1, F2, F3, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY F1, F2, F3 ORDER BY F1) AS rn 
    FROM tblName) a 
WHERE rn = 1
```

However, `RANK()` is most useful when you want to find "the most recent something-or-other" across rows, after they've been grouped by these 3-distinct values.

If all you're interested in is getting a list of distinct 3-value combinations in your table, you'll find it simpler to just do a `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3  
FROM tblName
GROUP BY F1, F2, F3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your query still giving error while trying to extract data from the excel sheet using it. But thanks by the way.

Comment: group by is giving me the exact answer I'm looking for.